# Why don't the elements in my slider repeat as expected?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I found this slider [on CodePen](https://codepen.io/gvzq/pen/OJVvzJz). I modified it to use images in the slider with different sizes. The problem is when all logos slide away, the slider jumps to the first one. This looks not good. I want a repeating effect, that after the last logo the first one appear but with no "jump".

What can I do to solve my problem?

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .slider {
  animation: slidein 30s linear infinite;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container .slider .logos {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 0;
}

.container .slider .logos .fab {
  width: calc(100% / 5);
  animation: fade-in 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955) forwards;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
    <div class="container rounded">
      <h1 class="text-center">Featured in:</h1>
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="logos">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take note of my modifications to your question. I used a snippet demo and I included the compiled CSS from the Codepen demo. This makes it much easier for your volunteer helpers to assist.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  .slider {
    animation: slidein 30s linear infinite;
    white-space: nowrap;
    .logos {
      width: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0px 0;
      .fab {
        width: calc(100% / 5);
        animation: fade-in 0.5s 
          cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955) forwards;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

to this:

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  .slider {
    animation: slidein 30s linear infinite;
    white-space: nowrap;
    .logos {
      width: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0px 0;
      img {
        width: calc(100% / 5);
        animation: fade-in 0.5s 
          cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955) forwards;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question needs some explanation. I had to scour it twice to spot the actual change, and it's not clear why you made it. See [answer].

Comment: Thank you! I do the edit. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: It's not at all clearer. We still have to compare line-by-line what you changed. Please add some _explanation_, not instructions.

Answer (score 0):

When you replaced the Font Awesome icons with images you didn't update the selector in the CSS to match. Also, the quantity of images is used in the CSS width calculation. You need to update that.

Finally, in the original demo the images were placed in the markup *twice*. You need to do that.

I also removed reliance on the surrounding markup to make the slider independently deployable.

```css
.slider {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-inner {
  animation: slidein 30s linear infinite;
}

.slider .logos {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 0;
}

.slider .logos img {  /* updated selector */
  width: calc(100% / 4);  /* must match the number of elements in your slider */
  animation: fade-in 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955) forwards;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="text-center">Featured in:</h1>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-inner">

    <!-- must be included twice -->
    <div class="logos">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/ff0000">
    </div>

    <div class="logos">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/ff0000">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```